# Batch file will not work for all commands

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have created a batch file to configure several settings on a vehicle controller. Normally I use a purpose built program to complete the configuration but in this case because there are several configurations I want to automate the process.
So I have used hyperterminal to capture the data/command that is sent from the purpose built program  via the serial port to the controller for each configuration.
I then made a batch file which includes the data/command that was captured with hyperterminal. When the batch file is run it should perform each configuration automatically on the vehicle controller.

I have found that the batch file will work for some configurations but not others.

For example the following configuration does work:

Here is what I see in the hyperterminal.

Here is the log from hyperterminal.

Here is the batch code with the data from the hyperterminal log

```
@echo off
Echo Enter the # for your com port (typically 1)
set /p com=
@echo on
mode COM%com% BAUD=38400 PARITY=N DATA=8
set /p x="¾@gms: 0  /¾@ gms¡" <nul >\\.\COM%com%
timeout /t 1
set /p x="¾@gms: 0  /¾@ gms¡" <nul >\\.\COM%com%
timeout /t 2

pause
exit
```

Here is the output after running the command

So the above command works well.

But when I try to do the following configuration it does not work:

Here is what I see in the hyperterminal.

Here is the log from hyperterminal.

Here is the batch code with the data from the hyperterminal log

```
@echo off
Echo Enter the # for your com port (typically 1)
set /p com=
@echo on
mode COM%com% BAUD=38400 PARITY=N DATA=8
set /p x="¾@swav: 1«¾@ swav" <nul >\\.\COM%com%
timeout /t 1
set /p x="¾@swav: 1«¾@ swav" <nul >\\.\COM%com%
timeout /t 2

pause
exit
```

Here is the output after running the command

You can see in the hyperterminal screenshot that the data is starting a new line. I think it is doing the same thing in the batch file command and as a result it messes up the command.
Is there a way I can adjust my batch command to compensate for the "configuration command" starting a new line?

---

I have now tried the following code based on @foxidrive comment:

```
@Echo Enter the # for your com port (typically 1)
set /p com=
mode COM%com% BAUD=38400 PARITY=N DATA=8
set /p "x=¾@swav: 1«¾@ swav"<nul >COM%com%
timeout /t 1
set /p "x=¾@swav: 1«¾@ swav"<nul >COM%com%
timeout /t 2

pause
exit
```

I get the following output:

```
Enter the # for your com port (typically 1)
1

Status for device COM1:
-----------------------
    Baud:            38400
    Parity:          None
    Data Bits:       8
    Stop Bits:       1
    Timeout:         ON
    XON/XOFF:        OFF
    CTS handshaking: OFF
    DSR handshaking: OFF
    DSR sensitivity: OFF
    DTR circuit:     ON
    RTS circuit:     HANDSHAKE

►¥@¶☺swav: 1
```

So the command is still not completing correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: @foxidrive I added the results to my initial comment above (see after the continuous line). The command still continues to fail - have you any other suggestions?

Comment: Your device may have local echo enabled.   What simple ascii command can you issue to your serial device to show that it is functioning?  Once you determine that the device is receiving your command then you can try more exotic strings of commands.  You can also try `com%com%:` with the trailing `:` to use a different mode of com port use.

Comment: @foxidrive I can confirm that the first code that I mentioned in my first post is working fine with the device. It's the second code that has the problem. What suggestions have you for other "exotic strings of commands"? Please note I'm very new to batch commands so if you can provide extra detail in your comment that would be great.

Comment: The exotic strings of commands I referred to are those that the device uses for control.  If the first `set /p` command works to control the device, then the technique is working and you now have to focus on the control language of the device to see what characters it needs.  Maybe it does need a CR/LF pair after the command, like the `AT` command does for a Hayes compatible dialup modem in the past and that would just use an echo command to the com port. `>COM%com% echo(¾@swav: 1«¾@ swav` but you may be aware of that already.

Answer (score 0):

The set /p has some limitations with the character set it can use.
Does this do what you need?

```
@echo off
Echo Enter the # for your com port (typically 1)
set /p com=
mode COM%com% BAUD=38400 PARITY=N DATA=8
set /p "x=¾@gms: 0  /¾@ gms¡"<nul >COM%com%
timeout /t 1
set /p "x=¾@gms: 0  /¾@ gms¡"<nul >COM%com%
timeout /t 2

pause
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

If foxidrives answer does not work (normally they do) you can work around the `set /p` limitations by copying your data to files and instead of writing with `set /p` do:

```
copy /b config1.bin>COM%com%:
```